# PHP! Как проверить ссылку на условие. Проверить нажата ли ссылка

Tags: php, html, веб-программирование

Проверить нажата ли ссылка.Нужно написать условие, если ссылка нажата, методом пост записаты в базу данных в таблицу 1!

Вот  ссылка:

```
<a href = "approvescore.php?id=' .$row['id'] . '&amp;data=' . $row['data'] . '&amp;name=' . $row['name'] . '&amp;score=' . $row['score'] . '&amp;screenshot=' . $row['screenshot'] . '">Санкціонувати!</a>
```

Comment: проверяйте переменные  $_GET['id'] и все остальные из строки запроса.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET["id"])){ //Кнопка нажата
        $id = $_GET["id"];
        $data = $_GET["data"];
        ...
        //Записываем в базу данных...
    }
?>
```